# MySQL Left Join taking too long to execute

Tags: mysql

So I have these two tables which I would like to join but it seems that the execution takes too long to process.

```
table1
|time_stamp|d_time  |
|1577829600|06:00:00|
|1577829900|06:05:00|
|1577830200|06:10:00|
|1577830500|06:15:00|
...

table2
|time_stamp|d_time  |d_value|
|1577829600|06:00:00|1      |
|1577829900|06:05:00|3      |
|1577830200|06:10:00|2      |
|1577830500|07:00:00|4      |
...



SELECT table1.time_stamp, table2.d_value
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.time_stamp = table2.time_stamp
WHERE table1.id = 15
  AND MINUTE(table1.d_time)=0
  AND table1.data_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
ORDER BY table1.data_date ASC
```

Above query will get the value based on table `id` and get only if the minute is `0` using the `MINUTE()` interval of 1 year. I have records from year 2014-present. The downside is the query executions takes >30 seconds. Is there any way to make it faster?

Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `d_time` time NOT NULL,
  `time_stamp` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_date` time NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1828559 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time_stamp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '240',
  `d_time` time NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4081
        DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Just to observe, there's no INNER join here

Comment: Why are you using MyISAM (and Latin1) for the first table?

Comment: And also there is no `data_date` column on table1

Comment: `table1.data_date` - no such column.

Comment: And there's no t1.data_date here

Comment: No indexes => Full table scan => Slow query.

Comment: There is I just don't include some column actually. I've updated my question. sorry for that

Comment: @Akina correct. I am new to indexing and I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: You are expecting about 8000 rows in the resultset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `INDEX` your column used in `JOIN` operations and `WHERE` clause. Assuming you have `data_date` column, execute this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `table1`
ADD INDEX `idx_on_table1_time_stamp` (`time_stamp`),
ADD INDEX `idx_on_table1_data_date` (`data_date`);

ALTER TABLE `table2`
ADD INDEX `idx_on_table2_time_stamp` (`time_stamp`);
```

And try execute your query again.

More about INDEX on [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization-indexes.html)

Comment: Ok I will try that. Does it work also if I have the data already? you can educate me about indexes if you like. thanks

Comment: @Pal3Kuno Yes it will work no matter the data is present or not. From documentation: The index entries act like pointers to the table rows, allowing the query to quickly determine which rows match a condition in the WHERE clause, and retrieve the other column values for those rows.

Answer (score 0):

These are incompatible:

```
  AND table1.data_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
 `data_date` time NOT NULL,
```

I suspect you are not getting the rows you desired.

Perhaps `data_date` should be `DATE` or `DATETIME`?

It would be better to have a single column of type `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`.  There is no problem extracting `MINUTE` from such -- just as cheaply as it can be extracted from a `TIME`.

What does "240" mean:

```
  `time_stamp` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '240',
```

Perhaps 240 seconds into Jan 1, 1970??

`created_at` and `updated_at` are probably never used, hence could be removed from the tables.  Smaller is slightly faster.